# Android MapView - Custom Polygon Overlays not resetting properly on a pan or Zomm

Tags: android, overlay

I am writing an app that requires polygons to be shown on a map.  I researched and found the best way to do it was to subclass the Overlay Class and override the draw method. It works fine--but when I scroll or pan, the shape and canvas location of the original polygon(s) do not go away - so as I pan I keep getting more and more polygons of the same shape - same when I zoom.  Here is the code for my custom Overlay.  Once I get my coordinates for the polygon shape, I call the setOverlayType method - so that the draw method has the data it needs to figure out where to draw the polygon.

It's probably something stupid!!

```
public class myOverLay extends Overlay {

public final int OVERLAY_TYPE_NORMAL = 0;
public final int OVERLAY_TYPE_SCALED = 1;

private GeoPoint pVerts[];
private GeoPoint pCenter;
private Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
private Path path = new Path();
private Context mContext;
private int overlayType;
private String pName = "";

public myOverLay(Context context) {
    super();
    this.mContext=context;
}

public void setOverlayType(GeoPoint[] polyVerts, GeoPoint polyCenter, int overlayT, String pn) {
    this.pVerts = polyVerts;
    this.pCenter = polyCenter;
    this.overlayType = overlayT;
    this.pName = pn;
}   
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapview, boolean shadow)
{
super.draw(canvas,mapview,false);
Projection projection = mapview.getProjection();
Point pVert = new Point(0,0);

if(this.overlayType==0)
    paint.setColor(android.graphics.Color.argb(50, 255, 0, 0)); 
else
    paint.setColor(android.graphics.Color.argb(50, 255, 255, 0));

paint.setStrokeWidth(2);    
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
paint.setAntiAlias(true);

path.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);
projection.toPixels(this.pVerts[0],pVert);
path.moveTo(pVert.x, pVert.y);
for(int x=0;x<=5;x++)
{
    projection.toPixels(this.pVerts[x],pVert);
    path.lineTo(pVert.x, pVert.y);
}
path.close();

Log.v("OVERLAY", "Draw Method Called");
canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

if(this.overlayType==0) //Icon
{   
    Point centerPt = new Point();
    projection.toPixels(this.pCenter, centerPt);
    Bitmap bmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.mContext.getResources(),     R.drawable.my_image);
    bmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmap,20, 40, true);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmap, centerPt.x-10, centerPt.y-50, null);
}
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer to my own question - I moved the Paint and Path variables from class variables to local variables within the draw method - something stupid indeed - map now pans, zooms and scrolls nicely with the polygon.